# What the best way to store data from SQL to element in JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I've used this method to store my data to element while I fetch it from SQL:

```
echo "<p name='" . $data['name'] . "'>product</p>"; // PHP code

<p name='product_name'>product</p> // HTML code
```

Could you tell me the best way to store element like that because I want use it 
in jQuery...

Comment: you can use jquery meta data plugin also if you get into lot of data

Comment: could i store data with id to differentiate p element each other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jquery data is the best for this

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

you can have something like this

```
<div class="HideDiv" id="hiddenValues" data="{Title:'title',name:'yourname',lastname:'lastname'}"> </div>

  var dataUI =  $('#hiddenValues').metadata({ type: 'attr', name: 'data' });

 dataUI.Title; // this will get you title
```

Comment: could i do that if i have much data to store in p element

Comment: @yeah joko, i will give any example wait.

Comment: @gov: do you have a link for that `metadata` method? I've never seen it before.

Comment: @sje you can see it here http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Metadata/metadata , but you have to download that plugin , its very lightweight has only one method

Comment: @gov: there's any method without plug-in !!

Comment: @Joko you can just use jquery' data but this plugin is just one method , you can get the method and copy to some of your existing librarys,

Comment: I don't think you need the plugin? Since 1.4.3, using `data-values='{"Title":"title", "name":"yourname", "lastname":"lastname"}'` and then `var dataUI = $('#hiddenValues').data('values');` should do [the same trick](http://api.jquery.com/data/). (As an aside, JSON keys should be enclosed in quotes as well, and officially JSON should use double-quotes.)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to generate JSON on the server, then using [HTML5 custom data attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/):

```
<div id="product" data-name="my name" data-price="10.20">
```

And:

```
var name = $("#product").attr("data-name");
var price = $("#product").attr("data-price"); // string
```

Since jQuery 1.4.3, all values are [automatically available](http://api.jquery.com/data/) in jQuery's data object, also automatically trying to guess the correct type:

```
var name = $("#product").data("name");
var price = $("#product").data("price"); // number
```